# Staff member has a diamond on a child meta but not on the main site

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderators

There is a user [Sara Chipps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4140/sara-chipps) (Engineering Manager at Stack Overflow), who is Moderator in Meta Stack Overflow but not the moderator on the main Stack Overflow site.

Also viewing [her network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2921/sara-chipps?tab=accounts) (other than Stack Overflow), on all the sites I can see her main site profile only. From the main site profile, there is no link to meta site, also the meta site account does not exist.

This is very new to me. Is this is a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not convinced this is a bug.

Comment: On closer inspection, me neither. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was a glitch. While we do make diamonds optional for employees, being a mod *only* on a child meta site kinda complicates things. After making sure this wasn't intentional in the name of science, I went ahead and fixed it.

Y'all *really* notice things, I must say.

#### Update

Wasn't aware of this, but we *do* now support employees having a diamond on a child meta but *not* the main site, which is how Sara's was applied. I did speak with her prior to making it the same, thankfully.

So yes, it's now quite possible for employees to have a diamond on meta where they need to speak as employees, but participate normally on main.

Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: One staff member did comment saying that "the community team has tightened up internal policies regarding [which employees] get a diamond and which do not". Does this mean that not every employee can get a diamond if they like?

Comment: Respondiling to the last sentence: This is what is called *a community* :P

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog Employees get moderator access as they need it, and we try to also observe an intersection of them actually _wanting_ it. If a dev is active on Aviation SE and only needs a diamond for a little while, we can certainly accommodate that. It would depend on the needs at the time and the position of the person.

Comment: @TimPost So if an employee wanted to moderate a site during their spare time using their staff rights, would that be possible?

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ I'm not even sure what to say there other than ... thanks for noticing the sentence.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog That's actually happened before (It was Bret on Aviation. Sklivvz also moderated skeptics the whole time he worked here (and still moderates the site). I also jump in on Stack Overflow to help out when I can (lately not as much as I'd like), but if I ever left the company, I'd still remain an elected moderator there.

Comment: @TimPost just curious, but how does the interface for giving somebody mod rights look like? Is this done from a central network tool, a per-site dev option or do you need DB access? Please consider posting a screenshot :)

Comment: It's just a radio button that devs see along with the rest of the mod tools, @MEEisJohannGambolputty... You can make someone a mod, or make them a mod due to winning an election. The first we use for employees or pro-tem appointments, the second, well, self-explanatory.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... Quick, screen shot this before they delete it! There's actually this special table and we have to prick our finger with a needle in order to be OH̀ NO ͠TH͘EY C̕OM̨E IT'S TOO LATE

Answer (score 4):

This makes some sense; she has a diamond on Meta Stack Exchange as well, presumably to give her communications about the Stack Exchange network a more official status.

> From the main site profile, there is no link to meta site, also the meta site account is not exist.

That's not uncommon; for a meta profile to exist, you have to *visit* the meta site. It's not generated automatically if you create an account on the main site. My [sockpuppet](https://stackexchange.com/users/10294207/spockpuppet?tab=accounts) has quite a few accounts on smaller sites ([example](https://stackexchange.com/users/10294207/spockpuppet?tab=accounts)) without having a meta profile there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification