# Latest blog post redirects to stackoverflow.blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, redirection

The latest blog post, https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/07/most-developers-believe-blockchain-technology-is-a-game-changer/ , redirects to https://stackoverflow.blog/ instead of the blog post that it's supposed to.

Other blog posts are not affected by this, so I'm unsure what could be causing the faulty redirect.

Clicking on the blog post from the blog home page also causes the faulty redirect to occur.

I'm running Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit). I've also reproduced on Edge Version 91.0.864.41 (Official build).

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Whoops, clicking directly from the main page redirects it.

Comment: Experiencing the same on our end. We're working on this!

Comment: (Katrina is from our Marketing department and is working on getting this fixed) :) Thanks @KatrinaDene

Comment: It appears to be fixed now... well at least the link ending in [`-2`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/07/most-developers-believe-blockchain-technology-is-a-game-changer-2/) and [`-3`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/07/most-developers-believe-blockchain-technology-is-a-game-changer-3/)

Comment: Should be fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We fixed this. Not sure why the redirect existed in the first place, but the canonical URL is https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/07/most-developers-believe-blockchain-technology-is-a-game-changer-3/.